# Live preview / WYSIWYG support (plugin?) for Notepad++?

Tags: web-browser, html, wysiwyg, live-preview, notepad++

I'm looking for a way to have a split screen view in Notepad++ where I can be editing my HTML/CSS in one pane/tab and be seeing the live preview of what it would look like in a browser OR simply in another tab/pane.

Ideally:

- in Notepad++ itself (using native panes/tabs as described above)
- the user could configure whatever browser rendering engine (Chrome, FF, IE, etc.) they wanted to view the preview in
- however, I could live with any variation of the two above, e.g. simply integrated with RubyMine using external windows/browsers
- or maybe, the preview only available with limited rendering engines (only Chrome let's say).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I haven't been able to find the plugin in the ***NotePad's Plugin Manager***, even when looking for "*unstable*" plugins.  So, I found this in another answer on SE...

---

### Closest Match:

- [**Preview HTML plugin**](http://fossil.2of4.net/npp_preview/home).

---

### Installation

1. Shutdown Notepad++ if it is running
2. Download the plugin from [**HERE**](http://fossil.2of4.net/npp_preview/home)
3. Unpack/unzip to a temp folder
4. copy the `PreviewHTML.DLL` file in the root of unpacked folder to the **Notepad Plugins** folder (usually `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Plugins`)
5. Relaunch Notepad++
6. Go to:

   - **Menu Bar** >

     - **Preview HTML** >

       - **Preview HTML** (sub-menu)

   This will launch a floating window title "*Preview HTML*" which you can dock just like the *Clip Library, Function List, Document Map,* and many other plugins.

   The window will refresh the preview automatically when you switch tabs, or whenever the document is changes.

Comment: Followed the process, but it resulted in a new window "Select Debugger". Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post a pic of the error

Comment: Just for the record, this plugin is limited to the Internet Explorer engine only.